# Pass Parameters to Yum With Puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install asterisk11 using puppet.

The procedure for installing asterisk says to run yum install asterisk asterisk-configs --enablerepo=asterisk-11

Currently I have in my puppet file:

```
package { 'asterisk':
   ensure          => present,
   allow_virtual   => false,
   require         => [Exec['yum update'], Yumrepo['asterisk-11']],
}

yumrepo { 'asterisk-11':
    enable         => true,
}
```

How do I pass the parameter enablerepo=asterisk-11

Answer (score 4):

I had better luck with this, just needed to add the --,

```
package { 'x11vnc':
  ensure  =>  'present',
  install_options => [
    { '--enablerepo' => 'epel' },
  ],
  require => [
    Class['epel'],
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what the [install_options](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package-attribute-install_options) parameter is for.

Try

```
package { 'asterisk':
    ensure          => present,
    allow_virtual   => false,
    install_options => [ { '--enablerepo' => 'asterisk-11' } ],
    require         => [Exec['yum update'], Yumrepo['asterisk-11']],
}
```

Note that install_options should contain full strings, which are passed to the package provider.

Comment: This works, but, what is strange is, the first time I run the puppet apply command on the file, it fails saying that it cannot find the asterisk-11 repo. But when I run it a second time, asterisk is correctly installed.